# jQuery won't remove one of array's elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two possible html chunks coming to my function, something like

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="result1">
        <h2 class="header">header 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="result2">
        <h2 class="header">header 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="result1">
    <h2 class="header">header 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="result2">
    <h2 class="header">header 2</h2>
</div>
```

I need to remove some of result# divs depending on headers content.
So when I'm getting

```
var headers = ['header 2']; // just for example
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var incomingChunk = $(incomingChunkHtml);

$(headers).map(function() {
    var headerLocator = "h2.header:contains('" + this + "')";
    incomingChunk.find(headerLocator).parent().remove();
});
```

In plain words: for each header's text I'm trying to find the header element, get its parent (a div) and remove it, regardless if this div has a parent (root) div or not. And it works for the first case html.
But it doesn't for the last one. The 'parent()' call gives me the div, 'remove()' call returns it (so I'm assuming it supposed to be deleted), but after all of that incomingChunk still has it among other divs.

Any ideas why and how to fix that, so the code would work for both types of html chunks?

Comment: The second example  doesn't have the `header` class, just `header2`

Comment: @Blazemonger a typo detected, sorry. Fixed it